# mysql How to convert the column of mysql select result to row

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql tableA， it changes it's fieldname every minute，i need it's fieldname，
so i do like  this：

```
select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS where table_name = 'tableA';

output:
+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME |
+-------------+
| min         |
| unkonwn1    |
| unkonwn2    |
| unkonwn3    |
| unkonwn4    |
| unkonwn5    |
| average     |
+-------------+
```

but i need  select  output like this：

```
+-------+----------+----------+---------+------------+---------+---------+
|  min  | unkonwn1 | unkonwn2 | unkonwn3| unkonwn4   | unkonwn5| average |
+-------+----------+----------+---------+------------+---------+---------+
```

how to get this kind of result ?

Comment: Check this out https://ubiq.co/database-blog/transpose-rows-columns-dynamically-mysql/

Comment: It’s easy for veterans, but it’s hard for a novice like me to understand

Comment: and  it's column to  row,  not  row to column